# How to implement arbitrary add operator in Rust?

Tags: generics, rust, traits, dynamic-typing

I'm working on an arbitrary expression evaluator in Rust,

Take `Add` operator as an example:

```
fn eval_add<T: ?Sized + Add<T, Output=T>>(l: Rc<Any>, r: Rc<Any>) -> Rc<Any> {
    l.downcast_ref::<Add<T, Output=T>>().unwrap() +
    r.downcast_ref::<Add<T, Output=T>>().unwrap()
}
```

and I got such error from the compiler:

> error: the `downcast_ref` method cannot be invoked on a trait object

It's obvious that the compiler doesn't know how to cast `Any` to `std::ops::Add`.

So what is the best practice to do such thing?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what is your goal? Make a function that can wrap every possible `Add` operation, or something else? Is the use of `Rc` and `Any` requirement?

Comment: Also please provide a [mcve]. The code you have provided (with relevant imports added), produces a different error for me: _error[E0277]: the size for values of type `T` cannot be known at compilation time_

Comment: Did you mean to write `T: Sized` instead of `T: ?Sized`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It's obvious that the compiler doesn't know how to cast Any to std::ops::Add.

That's because `Add` is a trait and you may only downcast to a type.

This doesn't work:

```
l.downcast_ref::<Add<T, Output=T>>()
```

Because `Add` is a trait, so this is really:

```
l.downcast_ref::<dyn Add<T, Output=T>>()
```

What you probably intended was just:

```
l.downcast_ref::<T>()
```

Since `T` is the type variable in scope that implements `Add`.

Your requirements are quite unclear, and the setup seems a little strange: you are passing around `Rc<dyn Any>`, but you also have this `T` parameter, which can only mean that that caller knows the concrete type of these `dyn Any` arguments, in order to supply the correct `T`. It's hard to say that this is the "correct" answer, because there are choices here that may not meet the unstated requirements, but it "works" and resembles the code in your question:

```
use std::rc::Rc;
use std::any::Any;
use std::ops::Add;

fn eval_add<T>(l: Rc<dyn Any>, r: Rc<dyn Any>) -> Rc<dyn Any> 
where
    T: Add<T, Output = T> + Copy + 'static
{
    let l = *l.downcast_ref::<T>().unwrap();
    let r = *r.downcast_ref::<T>().unwrap();
    Rc::new(l + r)
}
```

Note that `Add::add` takes its argument by value, so you *must* copy or clone it, since it is borrowed from the `Rc`. I've added the `Copy` bound, which applies to most numeric types, which should be sufficient. If not, you could `Clone` instead, which is more general but potentially less efficient.

If the two arguments may have different types, then you'll have to introduce another type parameter, `S`, and constrain `T: Add<S, Output = T>`. At this point I would again question what you are doing and suggest that you might need to rethink your overall design, since this is all very un-Rusty and confusing.

Rather than using `dyn Any`, I would strongly suggest that you consider an enum of supported types. The code will likely be easier to understand and debug, and should be faster too.